# Render partial view in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Is there any way to create a partial view like .net MVC in angular JS. I'd like to achieve the same partial view functionality in angular JS.

For Ex. 
I want to reuse a modal popup in all page so I don't have to write the same code on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ng-include` for partials, but if you are going to use this partial inside a `ng-repeat` its best to use a `directive` instead.It has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

From this question it is hard to judge what you want to achieve, but from angulars perspective you can always use ng-include to include template fragments.

I'd recommend to either provide a more detailed example - potentially with code example - so that you get better support. 
If you want to create something that is a partial in an MVC framework, then I'd say that should be a component/directive in angular.